# Invalid escape sequence

Tags: java, regex

I would like to filter out all words containing 1 number and 3 capital letters with a total length of 4. See my example here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?32taa

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();


for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){

    String message = resp.data.get(i).message;

    Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher("\b(?=[^\d]*\d[^\d]*)[A-Z\d]{4}\b");

        while (m.find()) {
            String s = m.group(1);
            result.add(s);
        }
}
```

But when i pass my regexp pattern to the matcher method, i get the error:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

Do I need to swap `\d` with another letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

- Your pattern is wrong, as it allows more digits - see http://regexr.com?32u3e
- Java requires double escape slashes...

Use regex pattern

```
\\b(?=[A-Z]*\\d[A-Z]*\\b)[A-Z\\d]{4}\\b
```

Comment: Thanks for notifying me about the pattern as well.

Answer (score 5):

`Regex` don't go well with `String`...

So u need to use `\\d` instead of `\d`

**-** When you write `\` **java** expects either `n` or `b` or `t` or `a` and few others... **after** it, but when you give `d` it gets the shock of its life, and think what the hell.. i don't know nothing about `\d`, So we need to tell java that `\` **should be taken literally by it instead of expecting it as escape character.**

**-** In the case of **.** (dot) it becomes even more complicated, when you give `"."` java takes it literally but its a regex so you need to make it look like that so you prefix it with `\`, so it becomes `\.` , now again the same problem as the earlier one begins as now java accepts `n` or `b` etc after `\` but it gets a `"."`, so we again prefix it with another `\`, so now it becomes `\\.`

Comment: Nice answer :D "it gets the shock of its life"

Comment: Some one just down voted this answer.... if possible please help me with reason..that would be very kind...and i will be able to improve this in a much better way....

Answer (score 4):

In Java, you need to escape the `backslash` with an extra backslash, when representing the pattern in string.

So, `\b` should be `\\b`, and `\d` should be `\\d`.

Comment: @Downvoter.. Any reason for downvote, you would like to quote?