# Java Regex issues with single character followed by number

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a simple Java Regex issue. I'm trying to get to identigy any pattern that matches the character 'p' + any number, meaning, p1, p10, p100 and so on.

By checking the actual regex at http://regexr.com/, the actuall expression i want is `/(p\d+)/`

While I have no issues using regex with JavaScript, I'm having a world of trouble with Java.

This is the part of the code that I'm actually trying to get to work properly:

```
boolean inBounds = (arrayPair.length  == 2);
String c = ("\(p\d+)\");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(c);
Matcher m = p.matcher(arrayPair[0]);
boolean b = m.matches();
```

This particular string gives me a invalid escape character, according to this ([Invalid escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553976/invalid-escape-sequence)) I should use double slashes, meaning the line should change to

```
String c = ("\\(p\\d+)\\");
```

This gives me a `Unmatched closing ')' near index 5 \(p\d+)\" error.`

So, I went back to http://regexr.com/ and realized I could write the expression as `/p\d+/`

So I went back to Java and tried

```
String c = ("\\p\\d+\\");
```

This gives a `Unknown character property name {\} near index 2 \p\d+\`

And it points to the '\' of the 'p\d' part.

Sooooo in another stackoverflow answer somebody mentioned I should use \\ instad of \ for d.

```
String c = ("\\p\\\\d+\\");
```

Which lead me to the error Unknown character property name {} near index 2
\p\d+\

Am I missing something here? I'm starting to go crazy about RegEx implementations...

Comment: Why would you translated the `/` (which is the JS separator for a regex literal)  to \ in Java (which is a string/regex escape character) and expect it to work? (In JS, `/(p\d+)/` is the short-hand for `new RegExp("(p\\d+)")`. Notice you have to escape the backslash in the string argument but not the regex literal.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the following `Pattern`:

`"p\\d+"`

You don't need to double-escape a literal, only the digit class.

The starting and ending slashes are not required in Java regex, in fact they'd change your pattern.

The parenthesis are used to delimit groups for back-references, which again, seems useless in the case you're illustrating.

**Example**

```
String[] test = {"p0", "blap10foo", "p*&^", "d10"};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("p\\d+");
for (String s: test) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: p0
Found: p10
```

Comment: That works fine, thanks! Just wondering... what if I want a /p\d+/g expression? How can I get a global search?

Comment: It's a bit different in terms of functionality. To perform the search globally you can use a `while` loop instead of `if`, which will iterate as long as the `matcher.find()` methods returns `true`. In case you are replacing elements, using `replaceAll` will generate a new `String` with all elements replaced.

Comment: See for multiline: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to backslash the parentheses. Even though SED requires this, in Java the pattern should be `String pattern = "(p\\d+)";`, which will resolve to the string (p\d+). In this case, the parentheses are actually unnecessary so `"p\\d+"` would suffice.